# Malformed token - facebook API using Python. Encoding issue?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've playing around in Python and the Facebook API - I'm fairly new to it! I'm copying and pasting an access token into my Python app from the Graph API Explorer as oauth_access_token manually just before execution. The simple app is a loop which performs some actions based on the status of some inputs. The loop also refreshes the token so that once the app is started with a new token, it should keep going for a longer amount of time. Snippet posted below, with IDs anonymized:

```
        oauth_access_token="ABCDEFGHIJL"
        auth_str="/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=XYZ1ABC&client_secret=[ABC2XYZ&fb_exchange_token="+oauth_access_token

        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)

        oauth_access_token = str(graph.request(auth_str)['access_token'])
        print oauth_access_token
        profile = graph.request("/me/notifications")
        profile2 = graph.request("/me/inbox?fields=unseen")
```

I realize this isn't particularly elegant way of doing it. Bizarrely, when I do this on Windows, it works fine and I have access to the my notifcations and messages. When I do this on my Mac or Ubunutu it doesn't work and I get this error...I think it has something to do with Encoding, but I'm not sure what nor how to fix it?

```
 Malformed access token ABCDEFGHIJK?access_token=ABCDEFGHIJK
```